# Why is time series forecasting different for each software?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, spss

I have 2 different software programs: SPSS, and Statgraphics.  I am using them for time series forecasting but

1. Each one gives different arima parameters when using the auto ARIMA model, and
2. The forecast is also different when using the same arima parameters in both software .

Can you please clarify why there are differences between them?

[image: analysis and data]

Comment: Could you please give an example model&data, and show the different results?

Comment: thank you for passing by my question, the data is from investing.com for one of the indices called (DFMGI), the data gathered monthly from Jan.2004 to Oct 2019.  the result from Statgraphics was ARIMA (1,1,1)(0,2,2)12, where ARIIMA parameters where all significantly less than 0.05 and the ljung box test was more than 0.05.  On the other hand for SPSS, the same data has been used giving ARIMA (0,1,2)(1,0,1)12, all parameters are significant but ljung box was less than 0.05 (0.012)

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't find a way to paste the forecasted results for 12 months.  I will be grateful if you can help in order to see that the forecast is different between the two mentioned software

Comment: When using the model found by statgraphics which is ARIMA (1,1,1)(0,2,2)12 in SPSS the result for the MA seasonal was not significant (0.889 for lag 2) although the same was significant in Statgraphics !

Comment: You should be able to edit your own post, see the *edit* button below the post! Then please edit the following information: Models used (maybe commands), link to the data, output & predictions. If you cannot include some, make a link here to some pastbin and I can include it.

Comment: See https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/estimation/

Comment: thank you very much for the help, but believe me that from yesterday I was thinking about this miss, how both SPSS and Statgraphics give two different answers in term of ARIMA parameters and results when using the Auto ARIMA in both software as well as different forecasts based on two ARIMA parameters.  but also I tried to use the same ARIMA parameters for both software but again different forecast results and different ljung box results!  really I'm very confused.  the data is the same with no transformation used but unfortunately, the results are different.

Comment: how can I know which software gives a better answer to either R or SPSS or Statgraphics while they are giving different results?  I know that all expectations are wrong but the forecast is giving at least a proper direction or clue.  I really need help

Comment: I tried to get your data ,,, but had problems .. please post it here and I will try and give you some guidance.

Comment: @IrishStat please find the excel sheet for your further analysis and help https://1drv.ms/x/s!Ajj3wvWS6XTwgRknwzbUvZuqCxyZ

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen please find attached a link to the data https://1drv.ms/x/s!Ajj3wvWS6XTwgRknwzbUvZuqCxyZ

Comment: @IrishStat please see the attached analysis as per my question above https://1drv.ms/w/s!Ajj3wvWS6XTwgRt1lOBGfxIJo2j-

Comment: @whuber I gave all the explanations needed, I was clear enough in my question, in addition I added the data and the results obtained from SPSS and Statgraphics softwares in my above comments.  Please unhold my question since I have an intention to learn why each software give different forecast although I used the same ARIMA parameters in both softwares (1,1,1)(2,0,2)12 ?

Comment: You need to include all essential information within the question itself.

Comment: @whuber thanks for the guidance, I modified the question to have all needed details

Comment: I appreciate your edits.  However, we prefer that the information be wholly contained in your post itself, because links to other sites eventually rot.  That would make the entire thread incomprehensible.

Comment: @whuber Thank you for your support, but I can not put all the information in the same question in addition to the data analysis because it takes more space and will not be understood too.  So I hope you accept this way so that we provide an easier opportunity to answer the question.

Comment: Take 6 screen shots from your analysis.doc file and create a new question and include them in your new self-contained question.

Comment: @whuber please be informed that i removed the links and i added a photo, is it ok now ? if yes please remove the unhold, thanks

Comment: @IrishStat thank you for your support, I added the jpg for the analysis and data for your considerations.  thanks,

Comment: When you have decided that my answer and comments have been useful to you , please upvote it and accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To properly answer your question regarding automatic model differences requires a little bit of history https://autobox.com/pdfs/econometrics.pdf to explain some different approaches to ARIMA model identification.

Model identification has and always will be an iterative process much like peeling an onion where clues are found and followed and possibly discarded culminating in a possibly useful model . Box and Jenkins in 1968 suggested this approach and https://autobox.com/pdfs/ARIMA%20FLOW%20CHART.pdf reflects a modification/update of this where additional/possible model complexity is found out in an exploratory mode . Think of the EDA approach of J. Tukey but in a time series context.

My first attempt in my disseration topic in 1968 was to do a one pass brute-force approach of trying a family of possible models to determine the best model via minimizing the error variance. In this regard Auto.arima was based upon an early piece of my software called AUTOBJ (which is the forerunner of AUTOBOX which I have helped to develop) while using a relative of the error variance the AIC to suggest the "best model".

Neil Polhemus , a friend of mine , the founder of Statgraphics was also aware of AUTOBJ and decided to use what was then a promising model identification tool call the Extended Autocorrelation (EACF or ECF [With regard to ARMA time series, what exactly is eacf (extended auto-correlation function)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58540/with-regard-to-arma-time-series-what-exactly-is-eacf-extended-auto-correlation) ) as the basis for his approach. The EACF failed to detect either latent deterministic structure of the need for error variance remedies and is no longer a tool of choice.

What you have are two different approaches ( two pieces of software) to model identification , neither of which deal with the effect of possible latent deterministic structure (like level/step shifts or local time trends) and complications dealing with error variance structure (like power transforms or GLS).

Visually and analytically your selected time series has error variance issues (higher variability at higher levels) and a level shift. A simple ar(1) model in a log transform yields one possible pulse. Neither of your selected tools of choice deal with this opportunity space. The residuals from the model I suggest are free of structure.

A series can be non-stationary in the mean. There are (at least) two different ways to remedy this .. 1) to difference ... 2) to Demean ie. adjust for one or more level/step shifts or local time trends .

In closing your series ( although monthly) exhibits no provable seasonality. Incorporating unwarranted seasonal differencing INJECTS structure which needs a counter-balancing seasonal component to provide a remedy.

I developed a useful model ( 1 level shift needed to deal with non-stationarity (period 58) and a simple ar(1) component ) here [image] with Gaussian Noise (here) [image]which provided the following Actual & forecast graph here [image] with wide limits due to the need for a log transform (N.B. how the error variance is smaller at lower levels of the original series ) . These forecasts look nothing like any of your three candidate models.

Also note that there is no seasonality in the original data , the model and the errors from the model . Tools that assume seasonal structure ..thus injecting seasonality into the residuals and then incorporating seasonal structure to counter-balance that had been erroneously injected should be critically examined.

The appropriate model is approximately a random-walk (.956 is nearly 1.0 ) with a positive drift (1.48) in logarithms.

Comment: thank you very much for your valuable comments, on the other hand I have just showed the differences among the commercial software which are giving a very tedious auto Arima, wherein my case as an engineer who is not expert in performing ARIMA model without the auto button, I'm really frustrated from the results which I believe that the responsibility for both software owners/producers have to illustrate why this is happening?

Comment: regarding the cyclic of the data and from some analysis I came to know that the data is repeating itself every 95 months and thus if I used this seasonality I will end up with a more complex Arima model like (1,2,2)(2,0,0)95.  I hope from those who are producing such commercial software to review the auto Arima methodology and to include not only the false auto Arima but to give the right tools which help the researchers who are not specialized in scripting.

Comment: I seriously doubt seasonality of 95 as there is no logic to this systematic behavior. You had I believe 190/191 values in the history thus at best you have two replications of  a seasonality of "95" . Again your series is non-stationary in the expected value BUT that does not always imply that the series should be regularly differenced either 1 or 2. In summary a plot of the residuals from either model should suggest sufficiency along with a clean acf . Be careful about the "buttons" you press.

Comment: When one uses AUTOBOX and the user does not know the seasonality , there is hyper-search where for each potential seasonality index , the "best model" is found by allowing both stochastic/adaptive seasonality and deterministic seasonality to be found thus empirically hopefully finding the best seasonality index. The user has to specify the range for this search. With 190 values it would be "silly" to consider a seasonality of 95 as there would only be two reps .I am not an expert in spectral analysis  to help you  correct your opinion that spectral software suggests 95 as the seasonality

Comment: When you are satisfied with my answer please upvote it (if you can ) and accept it to close the question . I suggest that you ask another question , posting all of your input/output suggesting to you that  a seasonality of 95 is appropriate to possibly  get help from frequency-domain experts.. You can refer that question to this one to provide background.

Comment: Thank you very much for your multiple and very useful answers.  I also know that 95 seasons are very ridiculous, but spectral analysis is very useful to know the periods in which the time series repeats itself.  For example, through the data attached to the question and through spectral analysis it is useful to know the seasonality during the 95 months which is the complete cycle for this data.  Thanks a lot for your support, I will try to use AUTOBOX to see if it is useful